# "or" in pip constraint

Tags: python, pip

On conda-forge, `tzdata` has version numbers like:

- 2022a
- 2022b
- 2022c

But on PyPI, the version numbers are like:

- 2022.1
- 2022.2
- 2022.3

How can I set a requirement, in my `pyproject.toml` file, to require at least tzdata 2022.1 or 2022a?

I've tried guessing

```
dependencies = [
  "tzdata>=2022a|tzdata>=2022.1"
]
```

but that doesn't work, it's not valid syntax. Is there a solution here?

Comment: I know you can check for compatible releases with version identifiers (outlined here https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#version-specifiers). I have not tested, but maybe something like `tzdata >= 2022a, == 2022.*` could work?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in a venv in python3 and version "2022.1" was installed. I have not used `.toml` files, only `requirements.txt` but I imagine it is the same concept?

Based on the "Compatible release" section under "Version specifiers" as outlined here
https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#version-specifiers

```
pip install "tzdata>=2022a,>=2022.1"
```